# Query to reflect actual significant change in data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Given a table with employee statuses and effective dates, how can I retrieve *just the data that reflects a change* in status?

For example, given the following structure:

```
DECLARE @STATUSES TABLE(
  EMPLOYEE_ID INT NOT NULL,
  EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  STATUS_CODE CHAR(1) NOT NULL
)
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (1, '2012-01-01', 'A')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (1, '2012-02-28', 'A')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (1, '2012-03-01', 'T')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (2, '2012-01-01', 'A')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (2, '2012-02-14', 'A')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (2, '2012-03-10', 'A')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (3, '2012-02-01', 'A')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (3, '2012-03-17', 'A')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (3, '2012-03-18', 'T')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (3, '2012-04-01', 'A')
INSERT @STATUSES VALUES (4, '2012-03-01', 'A')
```

What query can be used to result in the following?

```
EMPLOYEE_ID     EFFECTIVE_DATE      STATUS_CODE
1               2012-01-01          A
1               2012-03-01          T
2               2012-01-01          A
3               2012-02-01          A
3               2012-03-18          T
3               2012-04-01          A
4               2012-03-01          A
```

In other words, I want to leave out those records that have the same employee id and status code as the one before it, if one exists with an earlier effective date. Notice that employee 1 is listed only twice because there were only two actual changes in status--the one on 2012-02-28 is inconsequential since the status didn't change from the earlier date. Also notice that employee 2 is listed just once since his status never changed despite there being three records. Only the earliest date is shown for each change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some further experimenting, it looks like this will do what I want.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS rownum
                ,EMPLOYEE_ID
                ,EFFECTIVE_DATE
                ,STATUS_CODE
         FROM   @STATUSES)
SELECT t2.EMPLOYEE_ID
       ,t2.EFFECTIVE_DATE
       ,t2.STATUS_CODE
FROM   cte t2
       LEFT JOIN cte t1
         ON t2.EMPLOYEE_ID = t1.EMPLOYEE_ID
            AND t2.STATUS_CODE = t1.STATUS_CODE
            AND t2.rownum = t1.rownum + 1
WHERE  t1.EMPLOYEE_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Alternatively you could probably add `AND t2.STATUS_CODE = t1.STATUS_CODE` to the `ON` clause and change the `WHERE` clause to something like `WHERE t1.EMPLOYEE_ID IS NULL`.

Comment: @AndriyM good point, I like the way that reads better, thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  EMPLOYEE_ID, MIN(EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS EFFECTIVE_DATE, STATUS_CODE
FROM
    (
    SELECT
      T1.EMPLOYEE_ID, T1.EFFECTIVE_DATE, T1.STATUS_CODE,
      MAX(T2.EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS MOST_RECENT_PREVIOUS_STATUS_DATE
    FROM
      @STATUSES T1
        LEFT JOIN
      @STATUSES T2
        ON
        T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.EMPLOYEE_ID
          AND
        T1.EFFECTIVE_DATE > T2.EFFECTIVE_DATE
          AND
        T1.STATUS_CODE <> T2.STATUS_CODE
    GROUP BY
      T1.EMPLOYEE_ID, T1.EFFECTIVE_DATE, T1.STATUS_CODE
    ) SubQuery
GROUP BY
  EMPLOYEE_ID, STATUS_CODE, MOST_RECENT_PREVIOUS_STATUS_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CURSOR

You'd need two sets of variables: @PreviousRecord and @CurrentRecord

Declare the cursor for table sorted by employeeid and date

Fetch the first record from the cursor into the @PreviousRecord  variables - depending on your requirement register this as a significant change or not (write the record to a temp table)

Then set up a loop that:
 Fetches the next record into the @CurrentRecord variables
 Compares it with the previous record and if it matches your requirement for a significant change write it to the temp table
 Move the @CurrentRecord values into the @PreviousRecord variables

I'd be interested to know if the CTE method was more efficient